# Directory appears when I connect an external drive

Tags: windows, windows-vista, filesystems, ntfs

I had a folder named Downloads in the user folder (C:\Users\User). I don't know exactly what I did, but basically I tried to move or copy the folder to an external drive. But the folder was there in the same directory. After I disconnected the external drive the folder dissapeared. After panic, swearing and tears (hadn't yet related with the external drive thing), I created another folder with the same name (Downloads). Then when I connect the external drive again I see two folders with the same name! All my files were in one of them (joy!), but I don't understand what is happening.

Any ideas?

I'm using Vista x64, with NTFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the folders properties, if the contents dissapear when the drive is removed, you may have made some sort of shortcut or hard/symbolic link.

Comment: Indeed it was a hard link. But I have no idea how I created it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Chances are when you disconnected the external drive it also disconnected the folder the directory you speak of is contained within.

This is just my guess as to what is happening.